# Setting the default value in Struts2

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I am setting the value(kind of default value) for a drop down select value from action class in a page(given below). When the page loads the value is beig displayed but the other elements of the dropdown list is not displayed. here is the code.

```
Inside the action class
if(getTypeId() == null){
        String typeId = request.getParameter("typeId");
        setTypeId(typeId);
        }
```

Inside the jsp page

```
 <tr>
        <s:select label="To" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--Please Select--" name="typeId" list="typesofteam"  />
    </tr>
```

What I am trying to do is create a single page for sending as well as saving the mail as draft. The code works fine for composing the message ie I am able to access the selected item from the action class. But I don't know how to set the drop down element from the action class. The above method just sets the value but the other elements in the list is not displayed.

I will be very grateful for any help on this.

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Make `getTypeId` function inside your action / helper class to populate `typesofteam` list.
Struts2 automatically invokes getters for `name` using ognl.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the list, define a method in your action class:

```
public List<String> getTypesofteam() {
    // return types here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it in the constructor of the action class.